# (drupal 6) how to disable admin login by modify file in server?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In my drupal site, admin user name is `admin`.

Im worried someone brute force this account.

I hope when I just logged out using admin user name, I can temporarily disable admin user name by modify some file in the server through `ssh`

Answer (score 4):

You could *rename the admin account* by going to "**user/1/edit**" (or using the Users list), and change "admin" to something else. It will still be seen internally as the super-admin account, yet people won't be able to login using the name "admin" even if they try to brute-force it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Wildpeaks, but he doesn't really answer your question.

Locking out any user, including the #1 superuser, is easy if you have access to the database, either using [mysql over ssh](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-in-SSH-Basic-Guide/) or with a tool like phpmyadmin. To block a user, you need to set the `status` column to `0`. for instance, if you want to block user #1:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `status` = 0 WHERE `uid` = 1;
```

This method will prevent the blocked user from logging in and will terminate his current session.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to enable or disable users via SSH: [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

> drush is a command line shell and scripting interface for Drupal, a veritable Swiss Army knife designed to make life easier for those of us who spend some of our working hours hacking away at the command prompt.

- Use the command `drush user-block 1` to [block](http://drush.ws/#user-block) the admin account.
- Use the command `drush user-unblock 1` to [unblock](http://drush.ws/#user-unblock) the admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with wildpeaks' suggestion, or set the admin account to 'inactive' if you have another account that you use to do daily administration.